# Simple Random Sample $X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,...X_n=x_n$ taken with replacement, find maximum likelihood estimator for parameter $p$ of $X\sim Binomial(5,p)$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, random, maximum-likelihood

**Question:** Given a Simple Random Sample $X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,...X_n=x_n $ taken with replacement, find the maximum likelihood estimator for each of the parameters of the distributions below.

- The parameter $p$ of $X\sim Binomial(5,p)$
- The parameter $\sigma$ of $X\sim Normal(0,\sigma)$

**Answer** $$\boxed{\Large\widehat p = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{5n}}$$

**My Try**
I tried doing the problem:
$$L(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n p^{x_i}(1-p)^{1-x_i}$$

$$\frac {dL}{dp} = \frac {d}{dp}\bigg[\prod_{i=1}^n p^{x_i}(1-p)^{1-x_i}\bigg] = \frac {d}{dp}p^{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)}(1-p)^{(\sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i))}$$

$$\frac {d}{dp}p^{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)}(1-p)^{n- (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)} = \frac {d}{dp}p^{(k)}(1-p)^{n- (k)} $$

After deriving, let $k=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$  and the derivative equal to $0$

$$0 = kp^{k-1}(1-p)^{k} + (1-k)(1-p)^{-k} $$
Then solving for $p$,
$$ \widehat p = \frac{k}{2k-1}$$
$$ \widehat p = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{2(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)-1}$$

What went wrong?

Comment: Use `\sum` for $\sum$ and `\prod` for $\prod$.

Comment: `$\frac{a}{b}$` gives $\frac{a}{b}$ while `$\dfrac{a}{b}$` gives $\dfrac{a}{b}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MLE is given by $$\sf{L:=\prod_{i=1}^np^{x_i}(1-p)^{5-x_i}=p^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}(1-p)^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(5-x_i)}=p^{n\bar x}(1-p)^{5n-n\bar x}},$$ since $\sf{\bar x=\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}$, whereas you have written $\sf{(1-p)^{1-x_i}}$ instead - this is not correct as $\sf{X_i\sim Bin(5,p)}$. Note that due to the power products, it is much easier to maximise $$\sf{\log L=n\bar x\log p+(5n-n\bar x)\log(1-p)}$$ and thus we require $$\sf{\frac{\partial\log L}{\partial\hat p}=\frac{n\bar x}{\hat p}-\frac{n-n\bar x}{1-\hat p}=0\implies n\bar x(1-\hat p)=n\hat p(5-\bar x)}$$ which yields $$\sf{n\bar x-n\hat p\bar x=5n\hat p-n\hat p\bar x\implies\boxed{\sf{\hat p=\frac{\bar x}5=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}{5n}}}}.$$

Comment: Thanks, do you know why we don't multiply nCr with probability function of X ?

Comment: @AngeryDoge This is because $\binom ni$ is a constant, so it is unnecessary to include it in the likelihood (i.e. you will get the same MLE)